# Mobile Safari. Sudden movement in form inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iframe, safari

I have a form inside of iframe.

I see the sudden movement of the viewport after I turn on the fields of this form by clicking on the arrows on the virtual keyboard IOS

I noticed this problem in mobile Safari(ios8), and only when the form in the frame.

The "Run code" button not visible if open stack-overflow in iOS, therefore link to working example in [here](http://jsbin.com/maneto/1/edit?output).

Code snippets here:

```css
.a { background-color: #f00 }
.b { background-color: #0f0 }
.c { background-color: #00f }
.d { background-color: #ff0 }
.e { background-color: #0ff }
.f { background-color: #f0f }
.g { background-color: #0a0 }
.h { background-color: #a00 }
.z { background-color: #00a }
```

```html
<input class="a" placeholder="A" type="text"><br>
<input class="b" placeholder="B" type="text"><br>
<input class="c" placeholder="C" type="text"><br>
<input class="d" placeholder="D" type="text"><br>
<input class="e" placeholder="E" type="text"><br>
<input class="f" placeholder="F" type="text"><br>
<input class="g" placeholder="G" type="text"><br>
<input class="h" placeholder="H" type="text"><br>
<input class="z" placeholder="Z" type="text"><br>
```

IT REPRODUCE ONLY IF THIS CODE OPEN IN IFRAME

To check this:

1. open the website,
2. click on the first field
3. go through the fields by pressing on ">" button(on the virtual keyboard of ios).

After some pressing start twitching movement, and positioning of the screen in the wrong places.

Who faced? How to fix this bug with JS/CSS ?

Comment: You should include your [*minimal*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code here instead of linking to it.

Comment: I found a partial solution and make comment of it on apple-forum. 

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23671694#28423489

But it doesn't help completely.

Answer (score 1):

This problem haven't solves for long time

[discussions.apple.com/message/23671694](http://discussions.apple.com/message/23671694)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the scrollbar that appears on the iframe due to the length of the form in the viewport. If you do not have anything else on the page other than the iframe, turn the body's scroll bar off by using `body { overflow: hidden }`